# Pyqtgraph , help understanding source code

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I would like to understand some parts of the library *"PyQtGraph"*, especially when it comes to 2D plot.

In the source code, the two python files are the following :  `PlotDataItem.py` and `PlotCurveItem.py` (they are located in `pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/`). But in these two files, I don't see any function to plot. I mean we have only methods to save x and y data (`self.yData` and `self.xData`). Where are the methods to, stricly speaking, plot the data? (The equivalent to `draw()` in matplotlib.)

EDIT :
 Thank you for your answer. I am reading the source code and yes I found that there is something in ViewBox.addItem. In fact,I tried to remove some parts of the code in order to see if the curve disseapeared. The lines : scene.addItem(item) and item.setParentItem(self.childGroup) seems important. Anyway, you mean that I have to focus on QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView ? Would you confirm me that PlotDataItem is just a file in which x and y datas are "saved" and there is no "plot" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that PyQtGraph delegates the drawing to the [Qt's Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html). PyQtGraph will create a `QGraphicsScene` and adds `QGraphicsItems` to that scene. If you connect a `QGraphicsView` object to that scene, Qt will render the scene with the transformations (zoom, rotation, etc) of that view for you.

So `PlotCurveItem` and `PlotDataItem` are descendants of `QGraphicsItem`. You can find out which scene they belong to by calling their `scene()` method. It took me a bit effort to find where PyQtGraph adds the item to the scene. This is done in `ViewBox.addItem`, which is called by `PlotItem.addItem`, which in turn is called by `PlotWidget.addItem`.

The section on [Organization of Plotting Classes](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/plotting.html#organization-of-plotting-classes) is a must read if you want to understand PyQtGraph. Still, the PyQtGraph class hierarchy can be confusing sometimes because of multiple inheritance and naming inconsistencies (the terms *item* and *widget* are overloaded, and a consistent naming convention would probably result in long and unwieldy names). I have made a UML diagram in the past to get a better overview (see below). The blue classes are defined by PyQtGraph, the black classes are Qt classes. It is not complete, not all PyQtGraph classes are included.

[image]